# How to replace and save output in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tkinter, replace

developing a hangman game for myself, and got really stuck at the part where once found a correct letter in a word it would stay saved in that index place, I'm trying to implement it in the Tkinter's gui with return statement, using print here so that loop would not end. However I will display only code that I use for replacing letters in word instead of whole code for game, to try and not confuse anyone.

Main issue - cant find way to save letters that user inputs in the word, every time it returns new output

```
import random

underlines = []


def random_gen_word():
    list_of_words = ['happy']
    begin = 0
    end = len(list_of_words) - 1
    global random_word
    random_word = list_of_words[random.randint(begin, end)]
    return random_word


saved_random_word = random_gen_word().upper()


def user_input_for_game():
    while True:
        underlines = ["_"] * len(saved_random_word)
        user_input = input("Enter text: ").upper()
        if user_input in saved_random_word:
            # # below for loop will index every letter i = x from the random word
            # # if statement for checking if input was the letter in the word
            for i, x in enumerate(saved_random_word):
                if x == user_input:
                    underlines.insert(i, user_input)
                    # removes underline once a letter is found in underlines/word
                    underlines.pop()
                    print(underlines)


print(user_input_for_game())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not saving because you keep resetting it (`underlines`) at the start of the loop. So just put it right before, like this:

```
def user_input_for_game():
    underlines = ["_"] * len(saved_random_word) # outside
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter text: ").upper()
        if user_input in saved_random_word:
           
            for i, x in enumerate(saved_random_word):
                if x == user_input:
                    underlines.insert(i, user_input)
                    
                    underlines.pop()
                    print(underlines)
```

Test run:

```
Enter text: h
['H', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Enter text: a
['H', 'A', '_', '_', '_']
Enter text: p
['H', 'A', 'P', '_', '_']
['H', 'A', 'P', 'P', '_']
Enter text: y
['H', 'A', 'P', 'P', 'Y']
```

Edit: You can have a `underlines` var outside the function:

```
underlines = ["_"] * len(saved_random_word)

submit_button_actions
```

Just have a parameter in `user_input_for_game` and at the end return the updated underlines.

Comment: I wish it would be that easy, however, I used while loop just for this question, loop is not used within Tkinter. And once i click "submit" button which command is the fuction you wrote, it always comes back as resetted, any advice on that ? Imagine that I need variable "underlines" to be saved once function is done and add new result to it

Comment: @DanieliusPolujanskis I'll update the answer.

Comment: that's what I was looking for, I did as you mentioned, passed in the underlines as parameter and it works just perfectly now, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Np, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because `underlines` is reinitialized in the while loop.  Also you don't need to use `insert()` and `pop()` to update `underlines`, just use `underlines[i]` to update the required character.  Final you can use `random.choice()` to simply `random_gen_word()`.

Below is a modified code:

```py
import random

def random_gen_word():
    list_of_words = ['happy']
    return random.choice(list_of_words)

def user_input_for_game():
    saved_random_word = random_gen_word().upper()
    underlines = ["_"] * len(saved_random_word)
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter text: ").upper()
        for i, x in enumerate(saved_random_word):
            if x == user_input:
                underlines[i] = user_input
        print(underlines)

user_input_for_game()
```